# How do I display all the information in a Single tooltip

Tags: highcharts

1. How do I make this: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

with single line series like this:

https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Final chart should have single line series with volume

2. How do I display a single tooltip with the following information:
   Date, Time:
   Price:
   Volume:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting `tooltip.split = false` and using `tooltip.formatter` callback.

**Code:**

```
  tooltip: {
    split: false,
    formatter: function() {
      var point = this.point,
        chart = point.series.chart,
        pointIndex = point.index,
        date = Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %H:%M', this.x),
        volumePoint = chart.series[1].points[pointIndex],
        text =
        '<span style="color:' + point.color +
        '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name +
        ': <b>' + point.y + '</b><br/>' +
        '<br><span style="color:' + volumePoint.color +
        '">\u25CF</span> ' +
        'Volume: <b>' + volumePoint.y +
        '</b><br>' + date;

      return text;
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9gq7Lv4r/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.split
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: When you mouse over I would please like the volume bar to be highlighted as well as seen here https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume --thank you for your help!

Comment: You can achieve it like in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rLd1z9m2/. If this answer was helpful for you, please mark it as a correct one and upvote, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Wojciech!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to format the price with comma and two decimal places (ex: 1,234,567.89) and how to format the volume with comma as well but no decimal places, thank you!

Comment: You can use the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-currency-string-in-javascript. Check the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8k7ocpd4/

Comment: Can you please tell me how to display the mouseover price with 2 decimal places if the price is over 0.99, and 6 decimal places if the value is less than 0.99 (ex: 0.123456), thank you!

Comment: Simply change the decimalCount that is passed to the formatMoney function. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/anp4L9do/1/

Comment: Thank you for all your help! When I resize the navigator on the bottom from left and right at http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/anp4L9do/1 the mouseover stops working for some reason

Comment: It's because points are cropped and we should use data array instead of points, my fault. Working demo: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/anp4L9do/1

Comment: Hi Wojciech, It's still not working when I resize the navigator on the bottom from left and right at jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/anp4L9do/1 the mouseover stops working